# Current draw and VA ratings

Tags: current, transformer

I am wondering if a 12VA transformer (10:1, from 120 -> 12VAC) can draw more than one amp on the secondary side?

Just my thought process: 1A on primary @ 120VAC will be 10A @ 12VAC, if I am correct on this, can I draw freely 1-2A on the secondary side?

If not, I am going to have a lot of trouble finding a transformer for my project, I just cannot seem to wrap my head around this one.

Comment: For what it's worth, if you actually want a 12v @ 10A supply, eBay is littered with them for just a few dollars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are making a simple math error. As a first level approximation 12 VA ([VA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volt-ampere) stands for Volts x Amps, referred to as Volt-amperere) = 12 watts. If the load is purely resistive then VA and watts are the same, if it has a reactive component (think capacitors and inductors) then the wattage that can be drawn is less than the VA.

12 watts at 120 V =0.1 A not 1 A. Similarly 12 watts at 12 V = 1 A.

If you need to draw 2 A (or 24 watts) from the secondary then this transformer is not going to cut it for you.

Comment: Thank you Johnny, Mouser seems to have no cheap 24VA+ transformers, eBay is like looking for a needle in a haystack, I know I'll find something in the $<20 range eventually..

Answer (score 0):

> This is not an answer. Do not upvote it please.
>
> > @JonnyBoats can copy this or similar into his reply **if desired**.
> >      This non-answer can be deleted in due course.

As Jonny says, VA stands for Volt-Amps = Volts x Amps.

So, with one secondary and one primary winding, at any winding the A, V, VA 
relationships are:

Volts = Rated_VA / Amps
 Amps = Rated_VA / Volts
 VA = Volts x Amps.

If there are more than 2 secondaries the VA's for each add.
 The total secondary VAs must be <= the primary VA.

VAprimary >= VA_secondary1 + VA_secondary2 +

so for an eg 12 VA transformer

VA = 12
 Vin = 120 VAC.
 So:

Ain = Rated_VA / Volts = 12 / 120 = 0.1A

If Vout = 12 Volt then
 Ioutmax = Rated_VA/Volts = 12/12 = 1 A.